# how can I treat a button handler like a method call?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a VERY large asp.net application, it has many different .cs files in the project. I would like to trigger one button handler's method from another project. The reason is that in the .cs file that the button handler is it, there are many variables and methods being used that are private and I dont want to change the accessibility of all of them to public in order to access them.

SIMPLY put. how can I call the method "    protected void try_validate(object sender, EventArgs e)" from another method in a different .cs file?

[image]

I am trying to access resetPage from a different .cs file in the project. I HAVE placed the code for resetPage into a new method called WriteToDB but even that I cant call from the other .cs file

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible if you place the logic within the handler into another public method and then you invoke it from where ever you need to?

Comment: This seems like a better idea than invoking that handler programmatically (although I'm sure you can do that if it really is what you want to do).

Comment: i tried that as well I get same error even though I made it public..Why cant I access it?

Comment: Are you placing the new method in the same class?

Comment: yup its in the same class, same class as the button handler that is. The method I am calling WriteToDB from is in a different class. The class the new method WriteToDB is in is called "MVC" and the other class is called "Cars", the error I get is "Error 7 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MVC.writeToDB()'"

Comment: is it in a different project?!

Comment: i posted pic, it is in MVCReport and I am trying to call it from MVCForm

Comment: is it possible you are accessing a static method from a non-static one or vice versa? Can't think of anything else to be honest :S except to may be check that you are positively sure that you have written the method name correct, together with the paramaters and their data types!

Comment: it cant find method name :S the class the method is in is a public partial class.....HATE how computers..

Comment: if you do please tell! this is quite curious!